# Please consider reopening a question about a fairly recent, politics-specific meaning of 'pivot' [Question has been reopened]

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

The question is [what did Mr. Tester mean by saying to Dennis Muilenberg that you are 'pivoting' in the Congressional testimony of 737 Max?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517774/what-did-mr-tester-mean-by-saying-to-dennis-muilenberg-that-you-are-pivoting) It was closed nine days ago with the following explanation:

> **Closed.** This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.

To make clear what the poster is talking about, I transcribed a portion of the dialogue leading up to the use of the term of interest to the poster and added that transcript to the posted question. As a result, I think, the question now has the necessary "details or clarity" that (according to the close voters) it previously lacked. If I'm correct, the close reason no longer applies and the question should be reopened. Please consider voting to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for reopening the question.